# Leaflet Draw: Unable to to Drawing

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, leaflet.draw

```
Leaflet version I'm using: 1.7.1
Leaflet Draw version I'm using: 1.0.4
Browser (with version) I'm using: Firefox 92.0b2 (64-bit)
OS/Platform (with version) I'm using: macOS 11.5
```

I have a custom toolbar that allows to drop a marker and draw a polygon. Once the marker is dropped or the polygon is drawn, I add the object to the map and then I call another function to put some data into my database via an API request. At this point, if I create another marker and / or polygon, both the new object and the previously drawn object are both passed as event thus, creating duplications.

Code that creates a marker:

```
const draw = new this.$leaflet.Draw.Marker(this.map.object)

draw.enable()

this.map.object.on('draw:created', (event) => {
  event.layer.addTo(this.map.object)
  this.doCreateAnnotation(event)
})
```

Code called after marker is created:

```
doCreateAnnotation (event) {
  console.log(event)
}
```

Which console logs two different objects when I expect only the newest one. I have tried using `removeHooks()` however when I do this, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "dispose", this._tooltip is null
```

I have struggled for many hours trying to figure out how to reset everything to stop the duplicates, I even tried `map.removeControl(draw)` but I get an error that `removeControl` does not exist presumably because I am not using `L.Control.Draw`.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The `this.$leaflet` bit - does that come from any kind of JS framework? Angular, perhaps?

Comment: The `this.$leaflet` is VueJS. It's created by `Vue.prototype.$leaflet = require('leaflet')`. I did find a work around but it's ugly.